# How to search group words in div panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d05yg03y/) to show you what I want. I have multiple panels with words inside them. Each word inside panel are separated by `<br>`.

I have to make a filter and hide all panel who not match with words on the search bar.

Example : If I type `Hamburger Banana` in the search bar then I have to show the first panel and hide the other. If I type `Banana Hamburger Eggs` this will show nothing.

Do you know a javascript library or JQuery way to do this ? I seen [fusejs.io](http://fusejs.io/) It make exactly what I want but I see that it's made just for search inside json.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <!-- FIRST PANEL -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Banana<br>
        Hamburger<br>
        Pizza<br>
        Cheese<br>
        Tomato<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SECOND PANEL -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        One<br>
        Two<br>
        three<br>
        four<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <!-- THRID PANEL -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Hey<br>
        Eggs<br>
        Stackoverflow<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- FOURTH PANEL -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Search<br>
        Me<br>
        Please<br>
        Dude<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to allow a user to type i.e: `banana one eg` (even lowercase) and have all the matching fields remain visible:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/t0wL3u2g/5/)

```
$(function() {

  $('.form-control').on('input', function() {

    var val = $.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g,"|");
    var reg = new RegExp(val, "ig");

    $('.panel-body').show().filter(function() {
      return !this.textContent.match(reg);
    }).hide();

  });

});
```

While the above will show you **all the boxes which contain one of** the query words,
if instead you want to **show only those boxes who entirely match** the complete query string:

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t0wL3u2g/6/)**

```
$(function() {

    var $panelBody = $('.panel-body');

  $('.form-control').on('input', function() {

    var val = $.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g,"|"),
        reg = new RegExp(val, "ig"),
        matchMax = [];

    if(!val) return $panelBody.show();

    $panelBody.show().text(function(i, v) {
      var r = v.match(reg);
      this.max = 0;
      if(r){
        matchMax.push(r.length);
        this.max = r.length;
      }
    }).filter(function() {
      return this.max < Math.max.apply( null, matchMax );
    }).hide();

  });

});
```

Comment: This is really nice. I prefer to hide the whole panel like this : https://jsfiddle.net/t0wL3u2g/4/ . It's possible to search the whole of words in one panel ? For example `hamburger one`doesn't match but `hamburger tomato pizza` or `hamburger banana` will match ?

Comment: Maybe the `and` operator should be more appropriate. But I have no idea how can I do that in regex

Comment: @John I'd stick to the first example, seems more useful, but anyways added also an example where the requirement is to have only the box that matches all the query words.

Comment: Oh very nice. This is exactly what I need. Thanks you so so so much. I noticed just something. If I type `banana skmfjnksjklsglmqhmgqhmgohglhs` this will returns a result instead of nothing. It is normal ?

Comment: @John Yes. 'cause `banana` matches and if you have in two boxes the word "banana", both boxes will show up. Than if you type "banana one" only the box that has BOTH the terms will be visible (so not the one that has only `banana`) So to conclude word like `asdfgahsdjg` are ignored. You can play around the code to fit it for your exact requirements...

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function to the input.

```
$(function() {
  $('.form-control').on('input', function() {
    $('.panel-body').show().not(':contains('+ this.value +')').hide();
  });
});
```

**Note** that it is case-sensitve

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d05yg03y/4/)

## UPDATE

For multiple words (separated by space) use this function

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-control').on('blur', function() {
    $('.panel-body').show();
    var val = $(this).val(),
            words = val.split(' '),
            selector = '.panel-body';
    $.each(words, function(i, val) {
        selector += ':not(:contains('+val+'))';
    })
    $(selector).hide();
  });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d05yg03y/5/)

Comment: This is a nice approach. But when I'm typing Banana Hamburger this will not working. I need to make it work in this case

Comment: @LinkinTED Why when I type a space after my first word e.g `Banana ` this show all other panels ?

Comment: I was so wrong about the `.toLowerCase()` cause it will not work with `:contains` :(

Comment: @John, we won't get mad if you tried something yourself... the value gets splitted on a space. So adding a space will add an empty value to the array. Since all panels do have an empty val as well, they will be shown. Fixed it by checking the values length... https://jsfiddle.net/d05yg03y/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try on https://jsfiddle.net/d05yg03y/7/

this should remove extra spaces, accept insensitive words

```js
    $(".form-control").on('keyup', function() {
      var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, " ").split(" ");
    
      $(".col-sm-6").each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.hide();
        $.each(val, function(a, v) {
          var h = t.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(v) > -1;
          if (h) {
            t.show();
            return false;
          }
    
        })
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Banana<br>
        Hamburger<br>
        Pizza<br>
        Cheese<br>
        Tomato<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        One<br>
        Two<br>
        three<br>
        four<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Hey<br>
        Eggs<br>
        Stackoverflow<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="min-height: 150px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Search<br>
        Me<br>
        Please<br>
        Dude<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How can we avoid the other panels to target a panel matched with the whole of words ? Example : `Hamburger banana`will return the first panel and `hamburger banana eggs`will returns nothing

Comment: adding unique id to the parent or adding a class for each group and select the class instead of `$(".col-sm-6")` select `$(".targetted")`

Comment: `hamburger banana eggs` , `Hamburger banana hey one`, `hamburger banana one`, `Banana one stackoverflow`, `Banana one notFound anotherNotListed stackoverflow`

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't want a result for hamburger banana eggs. But I need result for hamburger banana. Sorry for my mistake in my question. I edited

Comment: There is a problem when type one letter. All panel disappear and when I clean my search, the other panel stay hidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126735/discussion-between-john-and-mamdouh-freelancer).